# Show "loading data" in fusion charts

Tags: javascript, charts, fusioncharts

I have a JSP that is rendering a fusion chart. The chart uses Spring to fetch the data it renders using MyBatis as the ORM. When I hit the hyperlink that render's the chart, the page takes forever to load because the data fetched is large. I want the chart to show the "loading data" bar in the chart when the query is running. The other parts of JSP should be visible and the chart should show "loading" when it's fetching the data. Using flash version of FUSION with XML configuration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Flash version, it is not possible to set custom/default message when chart is loading. However, default message "Loading Chart. Please Wait." occurs while rendering the chart in JavaScript mode. Also, if you would like to configure custom chart message can be set while loading a JavaScript chart using "PBarLoadingText" or "LoadingText" through configure(). Refer for more information [here](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/advanced/ChartMessages.html).

Comment: Will this approach allow the other elements in JSP to load first and then render the chart.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your page is taking lots of time to display because there is lots of data to be got from ORM. The "Loading Chart" message gets displayed when the JSP page is displayed and when FusionCharts is in its process of rendering the chart. But in your case, the JSP page is not rendered at all.

As a solution to this problem, try separating both the processes, such that there are two server-side pages

1. To whom control goes to when you click on hyperlink and displays the JSP page
2. On load of JSP page, call AJAX function and send request to another server-side page which retrieves the data required for FusionCharts to load. On receiving the data, the chart can plot the data. The "Loading chart" message gets shown when the chart is plotting the data. And, till you receive the data, you can show a custom message inside the div.

Since AJAX notifies you when it has come back, you can achieve what you want by doing this.

Comment: Actually I have included the JSP page that renders the charts in a main jsp using <jsp:include page="myChartJsp.jsp"/>. Any suggestions on how this can be modified as per the requirement.?

Comment: Can you let me know how you are rendering chart in "myChartJsp.jsp" ie if you are trying to render FusionCharts inside a DIV or using fc:render method to render the chart? Paste a code snippet if possible.

Comment: I am rendering it in a <div> using Javascript.
`var chartRTCNT = new FusionCharts(
        "${chartsUrl}/ScrollCombi2D.swf?PBarLoadingText", "ChartId",
        "1040", "320", "0", "0");`

Comment: Since you are using FusionCharts inside <div> you can follow the method suggested above. In the "myChartJsp.jsp" create a function (say loadFusionCharts) and call it onload of body. Inside the function, use AJAX to call your data provider page. When the AJAX function comes back with your XML/JSON data, you make your JavaScript code to render the chart to execute.Also, in the data provider page make sure you use PrintWriter object to output XML/JSON data to the caller of the page.

Comment: So I should set the data in the XML in a function and then render the chart in the body.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the code below and make sure you use "PrintWriter" object in the data provider page (Servlet) to output XML/JSON data to the caller (loadFusionCharts() function) of the page

```
<script language='JavaScript'> //in the head section
/* create AJAX object */
function getXMLObject()
    {
        var xmlHttp = false;
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e2) {
                xmlHttp = false;
            }
        }
        if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();

/*function to be called "onload" of body */
function loadFusionCharts()

{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 || xmlhttp.readyState == 0)
    {
    var url="someURL";  //URL of data provider page that gets data from database
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
/* gets called when AJAX response comes back after executing the data provider page*/
function handleServerResponse()
    { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var chartData = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (chartData!="") 
            {
          var myChart = new FusionCharts( "./FusionCharts/ScrollCombi2D.swf","ChartId", "1040", "320", "0", "0");
          myChart.setXMLData(chartData);
          myChart.render("fcDiv");  
            }else{
                document.getElementById('fcDiv').innerHTML="Could not get data to render the chart";
            }
         }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload='loadFusionCharts()'>
```

Comment: By the way, what do you mean exactly by data provider page.? I have one JSP that makes the chart. Have `setXMLData` and `render` functions in the same page.I am including the page in a main JSP. Where would you like me to write this particular script.. ?